# Selenium providing 'Errno13' but no location of error

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to develop a web scraper using Python, Beautiful Soup, and Selenium that can peruse the steam community marketplace.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time 
import selenium 
from selenium import webdriver 
import chromedriver_binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome("")
steam_market_URL = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_StickerCapsule%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&appid=730#p1_popular_desc'
driver.get(steam_market_URL)

for pageNum in range(1,6):
    steam_market_HTML = requests.get(steam_market_HTML).text
    HTML_parser = BeautifulSoup(steam_market_HTML, 'html.parser')
    popular_steam_items = HTML_parser.findAll(attrs = {"class" : "market_listing_searchresult"})
    popular_steam_items_URL = HTML_parser.findAll(attrs={"class" : "market_listing_row_link"})
    
    for item in range(0,len(popular_steam_items)):
        print(popular_steam_items[item]["data-hash-name"] + " " + popular_steam_items_URL[item]["href"] + "\n")

    driver.find_element_by_id_name("searchResults_btn_next").click()
    time.sleep(.5)
```

In theory, this should navigate through the first five pages of the steam "popular items" list and add names of each item + the URL for that item, waiting .5 seconds between each page switch (if I biffed here and my code won't work please let me know!).

However, after running the code I am faced with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seleniumTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: '' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Most other versions of this error that I have seen on SE provide a location after '[Errno 13] Permission denied:' and I'm a little bit lost on what to change here. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have 3 bugs

first do not put "" inside parentheses

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

second

```
steam_market_HTML = requests.get(steam_market_URL).text
```

Third name and id are two different attribute of WebDriver so you can call one at a time
in your case it is ID

```
driver.find_element_by_id("searchResults_btn_next").click()
```

It will be the correct code I hope

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
steam_market_URL = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_StickerCapsule%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&appid=730#p1_popular_desc'
driver.get(steam_market_URL)

for pageNum in range(1,6):
    steam_market_HTML = requests.get(steam_market_URL).text
    HTML_parser = BeautifulSoup(steam_market_HTML, 'html.parser')
    popular_steam_items = HTML_parser.findAll(attrs = {"class" : "market_listing_searchresult"})
    popular_steam_items_URL = HTML_parser.findAll(attrs={"class" : "market_listing_row_link"})

    for item in range(0,len(popular_steam_items)):
        print(popular_steam_items[item]["data-hash-name"] + " " + popular_steam_items_URL[item]["href"] + "\n")

    driver.find_element_by_id("searchResults_btn_next").click()
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work! I'm getting a 127 unexpected escape error now, so I guess on to that problem!